# removing a shared library link from a .so file

Tags: linux

`ldd` is a useful command that shows the location of the shared library files. Assume, the following command

```
$ ldd foo.so
      libpython2.4.so => /path/to/file
```

How can I remove that link so I will have

```
$ ldd foo.so
      libpython2.4.so => not found
```

?

Comment: What on earth are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: This is a test only!!

Comment: A test for what ?

Comment: checking if I get an error or it is ignored without notice

Comment: Oh yes, your program won't even run. That's why this makes no sense.

Comment: But I can show you a program that has two "not found"s and works fine That depends on the library

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can

```
mv /path/to/file /path/to/file_tmp
```

Depending on the library, you'll probably break lots of things doing so though.